# Java Mvc screencasts and tutorials?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I want to see in action howto make blog on Eclipse + Java + Mvc Framework? Do anybody see such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or even better try out [appFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) skeleton for building java web applications. choose one mvc framework and add project files using maven command. just take a look at the tutorial